# Switch/Navigate between Tabs in TabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

So I have 2 tabs in my tab bar controller.

I have a button in Tab 2, and if I click that, control needs to be passed to Tab 1, and it should become the present view controller.

```
//I should not use navigation for this because the view would navigate
the present view to the view in tab 1 ; but the tab will still indicate Tab 2//
```

I just need it to go to tab 1 when I click the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click the button, just have it send the following

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
```

That will tell it to switch to the first tab in its index (Tab 1)

If you want to add animation to the change, you'll use `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:`.  And to implement this, you'll use something like this:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:self.view 
    toView:[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] view] 
    duration:1 /*or whatever time you want*/ 
    options:/*specify your animation transition here, they are found in the UIView documentation*/ 
    completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }];
```

The options give you control how it transitions, and there's a nice list of all the stuff you can do.  Then the completion block lets you specify what to do once you're finished.  In this case, it will switch to tab 1 so it is the new primary controller

Comment: Could I bring some animation to this ?

Comment: It's possible, yeah.  There's a wonderful method of UIView (that I've started using a lot).  On second though, I'm going to edit my answer above to put this in just so it's easier to type and read.  It'll be up and ready in a couple minutes

Comment: Thanks man. That was awesome :D I removed "(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion:  " because it kept showing errors.  Animation is working. But why do all of them look the same ?

Comment: I wasn't sure if that BOOL block would work or not, so I guess that answers that, haha.  What do you mean they all look the same?  They're all doing the same thing and are supposed to be different?  Or do you mean that the animation selection is pretty much all the same stuff?

Comment: The animation does not seem Fluid. The new screen ALways abruptly comes for the bottom for all animations.

Comment: Hmm.  Unfortunately, I can't say I know a good workaround for that.  It might be possible to use a regular animation (setting it up using beginAnimations, setAnimationCurve, setAnimationDuration, etc., before finally telling to to commitAnimations).  It's possible this approach could be more fluid than the all-in-one approach, but it's hard to say for sure

Answer (score 2):

You can set your UITabBarController's `selectedIndex` or `selectedViewController` property to programmatically change the current tab.

Answer (score 1):

Would you be able to set the selectedIndex property on your UITabBarController?